# Unit test, function in Angularjs Controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, karma-jasmine

I have a controller with a function and a promise and I've had a lot of problems testing it with jasmine and karma, please help! This is my service:

```
primaryDistributionApp.factory('gridData_Factory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

return {
    realTime:
        $resource('/RealTime/', {},
            {
                "listAll": { method: "GET", params: {}, isArray: true }
            }
        )

};

}]);
```

And this is part of my controller (called gridInfo_Ctrl):

```
$scope.getData = function (){

    gridData_Factory.realTime.listAll().$promise.then(function (data) {

        $scope.data = data;
    })
}

 $scope.getData();
```

I'm trying to make a test in order to know if scope.data is Defined!

Answer (score 0):

grab any dom element related to the controller, get its scope and test for Data.

```
var scope=angular.element($('cssquery')).scope();
```

i don't remember jasmine sintax correctly but would be something like

```
expect(scope.data).not.to.be.truthy;
```

and there you can perform several tests in your scope/